# Why was Altera PCIe Vid Did removed in 12.04LTS

Tags: pcie

```
10.04LTS supported Altera PCIe vid = 0x1172 did = 0xE001
12.04LTS removed   Altera PCIe vid = 0x1172 did = 0XE001
```

Why it was removed ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why. But the file /usr/share/misc/pci.ids contains the mapping between pci ids and textual description. The database is maintained by volunteers.

The following command will update this database with the neweset changes from the maintainer at http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/

```
sudo update-pciids
```